# Compiling LESS files with broccolisj

Tags: broccolijs

I am trying to get broccolijs to compile a directory of less files using broccoli-less. I have altered the "preprocess" function as follows:

```
var compileLess = require('broccoli-less')
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler')

function preprocess (tree) {
  tree = filterTemplates(tree, {
    extensions: ['hbs', 'handlebars'],
    compileFunction: 'Ember.Handlebars.compile'
  })
  tree = filterCoffeeScript(tree, {
    bare: true
  })
  tree = compileLess(tree, {
      compress: false,
  })
  return tree
}
```

In my project folder I have a directory called 'less' which I include in Brocfile.js:

```
var lessStyles = 'less'
lessStyles = pickFiles(lessStyles, {
  srcDir: '/',
  files: ['main.less'],
  destDir: 'appkit'
})
lessStyles = preprocess(lessStyles)

var sourceTrees = [app, styles, vendor, lessStyles]
if (env !== 'production') {
  sourceTrees.push(tests)
}

sourceTrees = sourceTrees.concat(findBowerTrees())
```

Trying to build this project yields the error:

```
$ broccoli serve
Serving on http://localhost:4200


path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
        ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
  at path.js:360:15
  at Array.filter (native)
  at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
  at tryPathIndex (/home/kyrre/beekeeper-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-less/node_modules/less/lib/less/index.js:223:37)
  at callback.type (/home/kyrre/beekeeper-frontend/node_modules/broccoli-less/node_modules/less/lib/less/index.js:226:29)
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: So it looks like the problem is related to the @import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're probably looking for [broccoli-less-single](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/broccoli-less-single) instead of `broccoli-less`

From the README:

> This plugin is designed to compile a single, primary input file into a
>   single output file, with a tree of @importd dependencies. This differs
>   from broccoli-less, which compiles each .less file individually into a
>   .css file and doesn't support @imports or a single output file
>   depending on multiple inputs.

As an aside, it looks like you're working with Ember.js -- if so, I would strongly recommend using [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) instead of rolling your own build pipeline. It [easily supports `less`](http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/#less) and provides lots of other features.